# jQuery autocomplete not showing suggestions in Cordova/iOS App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm new using **Cordova**, and even newer with iOS programming. I've got a Cordova based application, which stores all the currency names in a **SQLite** database. It makes a query to select the currency name and stores all of them in an array, but when I try to run the *jQuery-ui autocomplete* it doesn't show any suggestion. It works fine in the Android version, but I don't know why is not working with iOS. Here is the code:

creadb.js

```
database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM monedas GROUP BY moneda",[],function(tx,results){
for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++)
{
    arraymonedas.push(results.rows.item(i).moneda)
}
//If the url is forms.html, then launch the autocomplete function
if(document.URL=="file:///android_asset/www/forms.html"){
    $(function(){
        $('#select-choice-moneda').autocomplete({
            source: arraymonedas
        });
        $("#select-choice-moneda" ).autocomplete({
            select: function(event, ui) {
                nombre_moneda= ui.item.value;
                var db= openDatabase("Facturas_DB", "1.0", "base de datos de facturas", 200000);
                db.transaction(selectID, exitoID, null);
            }
        });
    });
}
});
```

Does anybody know why it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked if arraymonedas is empty or not ?

Comment: Yes I did, I put the console.log and checked that it's full, but it's still not working.

Comment: Is your `document.URL` likely to be `file:///android_asset/www/forms.html` in the iOS version?

Comment: Thank you Zeratops and Palpatim. As Palpatim said, the problem is that the file is not in that location. Thanks for your help again!